# Scala and SLF4J :: pass multiple parameters

Tags: scala, slf4j, variadic-functions

Having the following code:
   log.info("parameters {} and {}", param1, param2) 
compiles and works well with SLF4J in Scala

However if I want to pass more arguments, I need to use Array:

```
log.info("parameters {} and {} and {}", Array(param1, param2,param3))
```

which simply substitutes first parameter with array.toString and leaves rest of parameters unbound.

The following code

```
log.info("parameters {} and {} and {}", Array(param1, param2,param3) : _*)
```

doesn't compile, because of:

```
error: overloaded method value info with alternatives:
(org.slf4j.Marker,java.lang.String)Unit <and>
(java.lang.String,java.lang.Throwable)Unit <and>
(java.lang.String,Array[java.lang.Object])Unit <and>
(java.lang.String,Any)Unit
cannot be applied to (java.lang.String, Any)
log.info("parameters {} and {} and {}", Array(param1, param2,param3) : _*)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7):

I guess it all depends on the inferred type. The log.info method that takes an array is expecting an Array[AnyRef]. So as an alternative to the cast you could do

```
log.info("parameters {} and {} and {}", Array[AnyRef](1, 2, "a"): _*)
```

But this won't work as there's a restriction on implicit conversions between Int -> AnyRef. For those, you'll need a type ascription:

```
log.info("parameters {} and {} and {}", 
   Array[AnyRef](1: Integer, 2: Integer, "a"): _*)
```

See this question for more details: [Result type of an implicit conversion must be more specific than AnyRef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26546299/result-type-of-an-implicit-conversion-must-be-more-specific-than-anyref)

Answer (score 2):

You should use a scala wrapper for slf4j like [grizzled](http://software.clapper.org/grizzled-slf4j/)

If you're not bound to slf4j, you should check out [Logula](https://github.com/codahale/logula). I've been playing with that recently and I like it.

Comment: Every project dependency is an extra future maintenance work. For example, "Logula" mentioned by @Falmarri in 2012 is now marked as "abandoned"

Answer (score 0):

what if you use string interpolation? like so:

```
log.info(f"parameters ${param1} and ${param2} and ${param3}")
```

Comment: log.info(s"parameters ${ 1/ 0 } and..") will throw / by zero exception  even if in WARN log level

Comment: true you can make it lazy val though. 

lazy val dividedByZero = f"${1/0}";
val levelWarn = true;
if (levelWarn) println(dividedByZero);

this will throw NpE only when levelWarn is true. I added semicolon to delimit lines since I cannot add CR

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Array(...).asInstanceOf[Array[Object]]
```

Comment: I did try this. It doesn't give an error, but it doesn't do the right thing either. It will put the entire array as a string on the first argument "{}" and leave the remaining blank ...

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I do it.

LOGGER.info("encode: {}, code: {}, length: {}", Array(messageWrapper, methodCode, bytes.length).asInstanceOf[Array[AnyRef]])

Cheers