# Scala: error: overloaded method value info with alternatives for log4j

Tags: scala, logging, log4j

New to Scala, trying to compute and log latency for my kafka records using log4j, but running into errors. Tried to look at some [SO articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940614/scala-and-slf4j-pass-multiple-parameters) but I think I missing some Scala concept here. Any help is appreciated.

*Solution1: Does not give an error.*

```
val currentTimeInMillis = Instant.now.toEpochMilli
val latency = Math.max(0, currentTimeInMillis - record.timestamp())
logger.info("record latency: {}", latency)
logger.info("record KafkaPartition: {}, record Offset: {}", record.kafkaPartition(), record.kafkaOffset())
```

*Solution2: This gives error:*

```
val currentTimeInMillis = Instant.now.toEpochMilli
val latency = Math.max(0, currentTimeInMillis - record.timestamp())
logger.info("record latency: {}, record KafkaPartition: {}, record Offset: {}", latency, record.kafkaPartition(), record.kafkaOffset())
```

*Getting below error for Solution2:*

> error: overloaded method value info with alternatives

```
[ERROR]   (x$1: org.slf4j.Marker,x$2: String,x$3: Object*)Unit <and>
[ERROR]   (x$1: org.slf4j.Marker,x$2: String,x$3: Any,x$4: Any)Unit <and>
[ERROR]   (x$1: String,x$2: Object*)Unit
[ERROR]  cannot be applied to (String, Long, Integer, Long)
[ERROR] logger.info("record latency: {}, record KafkaPartition: {}, record Offset: {}", latency, record.kafkaPartition(), record.kafkaOffset())
[ERROR]                  ^
[ERROR] one error found
```

Comment: Maybe it is an autoboxing failure from your primitive types. As a workaround, you could use String interpolation directly (`s"record latency ${latency}..."`). I think it works with two arguments because there is an overload that does not require varargs. You could also get a Scala wrapper for SLF4J, those usually also support lazy log messages which is a nice feature as it can skip generating the message and its inputs depending on log level.

Comment: Adding `(s"record latency ${latency}...")` did not help. Looking into Scala wrapper for SLF4J option.

Comment: What error do you get with the string interpolation? Remember to remove the now redundant extra arguments. All that is left is `logger.info(s"....")`.

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't put it correctly, that worked! `logger.info(s"record latency: ${latency}, record KafkaPartition: ${record.kafkaPartition()}, record Offset: ${record.kafkaOffset()}")`

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this before with Scala. Adding `.toString` to log arguments that aren't Strings will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could do:

```
logger.info("record latency: {}, record KafkaPartition: {}, record Offset: {}", latency: java.lang.Long, record.kafkaPartition(): Integer, record.kafkaOffset(): java.lang.Long)
```

to bypass the type restrictions.